# Numlock on by default on Linux Kali

Tags: linux, boot, kali-linux, numlock

I am fairly new to this version of Linux.

I have it set so that when it boots, it automatically boots into the GUI for the operating system. This means when I load up the OS I am greeted with a login screen. My question is how to have it so NumLock is on by default at this point.

I have looked at ways of doing it and most the ways involve using NumLockX. I have gone off several forums on how to do it, [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/155683/491642), [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NumLock), and [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-linux-turn-on-num-lock-on-gnome-startup/). However they are for Ubuntu and Debian versions of Linux and they proved unsuccessful when I tried them on Kali. Is anyone aware of how to do it on Linux Kali? I would appreciate any help.

Dan

Comment: Please [don't cross-post between multiple Stackexchange sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).  http://superuser.com/questions/1068057/numlock-on-by-default-on-kali-linux

Comment: @EightBitTony I do apologise but I haven't really got much interest on either post and I can't seem to find an answer on how to do what I am after

Comment: The questions are 1 hour old, at a time of day when (frankly) the majority of readers are either in bed, or at work.  Maybe give it more than 60 minutes.

Comment: @EightBitTony You don't happen to know the answer do you?